# Code to prevent path traversal in python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

I have developed a web application which is vulnerable to path traversal attack. The application is using python cgi. What code can be used to prevent the path traversal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help you fix/debug your code. Questions like this invite opinions, and end up being contentious. This is not the place to ask an open ended question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Comment: In general, a path traversal attack means that you give access to files that are outside your web root. When your python codes reads files, you need to validate the path whether it is a path the user should be allowed to access. In general, you can never trust input from users. You need to check, validated or encode any input from users.